# Clone tree data structure with back references?

Tags: c#, clone

I want to clone a tree of objects, where every node also references the parent node:

[image]

**How do I avoid cloning parents more than once at a time?** Every node is a `Guy`. When I clone the root guy who has no parent, I clone its children and children's children. The children's parent mustn't be cloned a second time because I've cloned it already. So what cloning technique do I use? And how does it avoid my dilemma?

```
public class Guy
{
    private Guy parent = null;
    private List<Guy> children = new List<Guy>();
    private double x, y, z;
}
```

Thanks for any useful advise!

*(If the question is duplicate and you let me know, I will delete it, no problem.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding, the cloning can be done with the following recursive function.

```cs
public Guy Clone(Guy original, Guy parent = null)
{
    Guy originalClone = new Guy();
    originalClone.parent = parent;
    foreach (Guy child in original.children)
    {
        originalClone.children.Add(Clone(child,originalClone));
    }
    return originalClone;
}
```

A root to the copy of the tree is returned by the following call.

```
Guy RootOfCopy = Clone(RootOfOriginal);
```

Comment: Yo, I ended up with implementing [`ICloneable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx). It's about the same as what you have suggested: cloning manually and looking out for the parent node. So I'll just "close" the question by accepting.